Clarity - with the change to requiring App Ids how do we add new SharePoint sites
Microsoft changed the way you use PnP.PowerShell it now has to be a registered App which I created.
Clarity requires PnP.PowerShell to enable Clarity on a Site
I can now use PnP.Powershell to log in but I cannot add new instances of Clarity to a Site Collection - it give me an error "Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation"
How are users adding new Sites to Clarity?
Created the Application ID for PnP.PowerShell
But Step 2 in the Microsoft Instructions no longer works
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/clarity/third-party-integrations/sharepoint-integration#add-clarity-to-a-specific-sharepoint-site
